# What is the name of concept: temporal numeric dataset with summing/aggregation operations?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, temporal

I have a, say, daily `income` data set of numeric [Temporal Properties](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/TemporalProperty.html), like:

```
Date       Income
2012-01-03 12
2012-01-05 11
2012-01-06 28
2012-01-07 9
2012-01-08 15
```

I'm doing several operations on it:

- Aggregation: group by week/sum by value;
- Interpolation;
- Shifting/cyclic shifting over time interval;
- Various smoothing;
- Summing/subtracting datasets (combined with interpolation);
- Calculating difference to a next value - resulting in a "daily income change" dataset;

Another example is currency `rate` given in [Effectivity](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Effectivity.html) intervals like:

```
StartDate  EndDate    Rate
2012-01-03 2012-01-04 12
2012-01-05 2012-01-05 11
2012-01-06 2012-01-06 28
2012-01-07 2012-01-07 9
2012-01-08 2012-01-12 15
```

and operations like:

- multiplying `income` dataset by `rate` dataset;
- converting `income` from one-time events set to a sequence of `Effectivities` (till the next known value) and vice versa;

Additionally, the `Efiictivities` set can be dense (without gaps) or with gaps, can allow or not allow overlaps.

What is the name of this concept? I didn't find any things like this in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018915/temporal-libraries-for-java), for instance.

It's a kind of numerical representation of a function, but pretty specific one.

Ideally, I'm lookinng for a Java library with Hibernate support to do these.

Comment: If that is income per day, then it's just an event, not a temporal property.

Comment: `@The Nail` - depends on what you do with it. SICP defines data type as a set of **operations** you can do on an entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key search term is "TimeSeries"

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950004/java-library-to-do-time-series-analysis

This has some good links to Java implementations.

But Java really isn't the best language for this - maybe try Python with Numpy or R.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the set of algorithms that look at a incoming stream of data and extract properties from them, then take a look at [online algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm).

Comment: I'm rather looking for libraries/algorithms that operate on an existing historical sequences, and don't do anything too complex, but encapsulate the operations in a reusable way. Thank you anyway.